# Can't connect to SQL server from asp.net website, receiveing a network path not found error message

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis

The SQL server is Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 running on IIS 7.1.

I'm using an instance of the SQL server and running a different port on IIS(8090) to access the website, as this is not the default website.

My SQL server is working, I've tested it using the following ways.

1. Connect to it directly from SQL management studio
2. connect to the server using VPN and using visual studio from my development machine to connect to run the website, no issues encounters and everything works.
3. Connect to the server using VPN using my test environment through IIS on a virtual machine, everything is working as intended.

The issue occurs from my live server when trying to access the SQL through IIS.

I feel like the issue has to do with IIS, I've checked all the ports and permissions, but I can't figure out why this might be happening

Here is the stack code that i receive.

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6568558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6595000
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +219
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6597311
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6597891
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +942
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +6601145
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2102
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1079
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6605639
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +292
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +420
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +277
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +3326331
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +176
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +51
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +146
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +36
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297
```

This is my connection string, I've replaced the login credentials with asterisks.

```
<add name="BakeryConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  connectionString="Data Source= 192.168.2.10\BAKERYDB,52468;Initial Catalog=Bakery;Integrated Security=False;User ID=*******;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Comment: Is tcp enabled protocol?

Comment: tcp, named pipes, and sharing is enabled, I've tested different ports and the same issue occurs, from all the tests that i've done the issue seems to be related to iis and not sql.

Comment: Have you tried building the connection string with Visual Studio? Have you tried using say osql to try and just connect? Or sqlcmd using the same connection parameters?

Comment: @MikeCheel I have not tried using visual studio connection string, but I did try sqlcmd and it was working fine. 

Like I said in my post, I suspect this is not a SQL issue as I'm able to connect to it from all other locations except the local server using IIS.

Comment: I'm just trying to whittle things down. What about application pool account? Does it have permissions to the database?

Comment: @MikeCheel Yes, I've initially used the default App Pool, then switched it to a new one and created an account in the DB for it to use.

I have a test environment where I do all my testing on it everything works fine, what I've tried is going through a VPN to the test environment and connecting to that database which was working fine when using the local machine and the same issue occurs.

Comment: Try connecting with sqlcmd and then execute a query with that account.

Comment: @MikeCheel The SQL is using SQL authentication, and while it does connect to the DB with sqlcmd it does not display any of the data, only the headers.

When using the sqlcmd with the -U tag and the SQL account everything is displaying properly

Comment: @MikeCheel I've commented out all my code in the Page_Load method for the page and tried to open the it, but I still get the same error for some reason, there is no call to the SQL server at all as all of it is commented out, any ideas?

Comment: You're still getting the sql error even when not calling sql?

Comment: @MikeCheel Seems to be the case.

Comment: And you recompiled? Are yuo running Debug? something sounds off here.

Comment: @MikeCheel I've found the bug, forgot about a drop down list that was still using static referencing instead of dynamic.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Thaks for commenting the resolutiion. It sounded like something fishy was going on. =)

Answer (score 0):

Drop down list was using static reference to an incorrect server